# How to implement class methods with attributes of another class?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have three models, BoletoConfig(BilletConfig),Tickets and CategoryTicket, one ticket has a CategoryTicket and CategoryTicket has a BilletConfig, BilletConfig has an attribute with the days for the billet due, I want to create a method in the tickets class to calculate the due date.

I have doubts if I use the decorator @property or @classmethod, which would be the best choice and why? and how would i get the value of days_to_become_due from my BoletoConfig class in tickets?

This my /billets/models.BoletoConfig

```py
class BoletoConfig(models.Model):
    base_amount = models.DecimalField(
        db_column='valor_base',
        max_digits=10,
        decimal_places=2,
        verbose_name='valor base do boleto',
    )
    check_specialization_for_amount = models.BooleanField(
        default=False,
        db_column='especializacao_protocolo',
        verbose_name='especialização do protocolo',
    )
    days_to_become_due = models.IntegerField(
        db_column='dias_vencimento',
        verbose_name='dias até vencimento',
    )

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'boletos_boleto_configuracao'
        verbose_name = 'boletos_configuração'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.base_amount
```

This my /tickets/models.tickets

```py
class Ticket(TimestampedModel, permissions.TicketPermission):
    """A ticket requested by someone to address a situation"""
    requested_by = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        models.PROTECT,
        db_column='requerido_por',
        related_name='+',
    )
    show_ticket_for_request_user = models.BooleanField(
        default=True,
        db_column='mostrar_ticket_para_requerente',

    )
    message = models.CharField(
        max_length=4000,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        db_column='mensagem',
    )
    status = models.ForeignKey(
        Status,
        models.PROTECT,
    )
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        Category,
        models.PROTECT,
    )
    files = models.CharField(max_length=4000, blank=True, null=True)
    boleto_id = models.UUIDField(
        db_column='boleto_id',
        verbose_name='Uuid Boleto',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )

@classmethod
    def get_boleto_duo_date(self, category):
        days_to_due = 'category__boleto_config__days_to_become_due'
        return self.ticket.created_at + timedelta(days=days_to_due)
```

This my /tickets/models.CategoryTicket

```py
class Category(TimestampedModel):
    """
        Represents what the ticket is about.
        EX: Change lesson attendance, change activity grade.
    """
.
.
.
.
    boleto_config = models.ForeignKey(
        BoletoConfig,
        models.PROTECT,
        db_column='boleto_config_id',
        verbose_name='configuração de boleto',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
```

Comment: I would use `@cached_property`, and none of your suggestions ;)